# Update a label with speed every x seconds

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nstimer, cllocation

I'm developing my first iPhone application. I have to update a label with the device speed every x seconds. I have created my own `CLController` and I can get device speed but I don't know if I have got to use `NSTimer` to update my label. How can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can schedule the timer like this

```
NSTimer *myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:YOUR_INTERVAL 
                       target:self 
                       selector:@selector(updateLabel) 
                       userInfo:nil 
                       repeats:YES];
```

Now below method will get called in every YOUR_INTERVAL (in seconds) periods

```
- (void) updateLabel {
    myLabel.text = @"updated text";
}
```

To stop the timer you could call invalidate on the timer object. So you might want to save the timer as a member variable, so that you can access it anywhere.

```
[timer invalidate];
```

Comment: You also need to fire the timer by adding it to MainRunLoop `[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:myTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];`

Answer (score 2):

you are right you have to use NSTimer.
You will be calling one method after x seconds and updating the label.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:x  target:self selector:@selector(updateLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)updateLabel
{
    // update your label
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to add the timer to the runloop, or else it won't do anything.

Comment: Thank You! Can I use methods with paramters in NSTimer selector?